# Как не делать перенос строки внутри элемента <table> на следующую страницу в PDF?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, pdf

Сейчас разрыв между строками таблицы (элементами tr) может происходить так, что большая часть страницы будет пуста и только на следующей странице будет последующая строка таблицы. Как сделать так, чтобы разрыв между строками был только в конце странице, если строка в этом месте закончилась?